# Bluetooth CSR8510 not connecting to multiple BLE devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

On my oDroid XU4 (Android 7.1.2) I'm using the Hardkernel Bluetooth CSR 4.0 USB dongle, this has the chipset CSR8510. It has some strange behaviour. I want to connect 4 BLE devices, however, it is only accepting one. The second one fails during connecting, sometimes with the error "Can't communicate to bluetooth device XX". Multiple Bluetooth classic / high speed (BT2 / BT3) are working.

We did find that when we first connect a bluetooth 2.0 speaker, that it is possible to connect multiple BLE devices...

I've been browsing around in BlueSuite (2.5.0), however, I cannot seem to find a setting that should fix this.

Can anybody explain this behaviour? And how can I fix it so I can connect 4 BLE devices, without the need of a workaround 2.0 speaker?

Thanks!
Rogier

Comment: How are you confirming that the BLE devices are connected or not connected? Have you tried to install an Android BLE Scanner app to help diagnose the problem. There is one from Bluepixel that is fairly good. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner&hl=en_US

Comment: Unfortunately, this app doesn't really help with debugging. Or am I missing something? Currently I'm checking in the android bluetooth menu if it's connected or not. Also if the input devices actually give input. For the rest I'm using the logcat to check any errors.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46556604/295004 and it may be worth looking at: http://blog.bluetooth.com/debugging-bluetooth-with-an-android-app